# Animation with multiple objects

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I would like to make different animations for a character based on the different weapons the character could pick up, but i do not see the efficient way to achieve that or that I may be doing it the wrong way.

I would like to provide the animations of the character using and holding different weapons.

For example, I have the character with the arms down, how could I make him lift his arms picking up the gun as if he is going to shoot, and also for all the other weapons the zombie may use.

What I have done is parenting the weapon with the hand bone and than animate, but that seems to force you to import a separete blender file for every animation with the character animated with every weapon. And seems to me it is to much files to manage.

I am working with Blender and Unity. Thanks!